# How to Calculate Sum of a Finite Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does anyone know how to calculate this sum of finite series
$$
S = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{ak + b}}} 
$$
with a and b are positive real numbers.

Comment: Is that meant to be a partial sum from $k=1$ to $n$? It's not really an infinite series with the $n$ on top, did you mean to put $\infty$ on top?

Comment: It's a finite series. Sorry for typos, my bad.

Comment: There is no elementary expression for that sum. You can find asymptotic expressions for it when $n\to\infty$, though. It will behave much like $\int_1^n(ax+b)^{-1}\,dx$ for large $n$, and that is an integral you can easily evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

You an write that as:
$$
\frac{1}{a} \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k + b / a}
$$
If $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer, you can express this in terms of harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it as $(\Psi(b/a+n+1)-\Psi(b/a+1))/a$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sum in terms of the [$\psi$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), here is a result by maple

$$ \frac{1}{a}\psi \left( n+1+{\frac {b}{a}} \right) -\frac{1}{a}\psi \left( 1+{\frac {
b}{a}} \right). $$